# Modifying ktors call co-routine context

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So I'm using `ktor` and want to have some data available throughout the context, via a `ThreadLocal`. What I am looking at is:

```
val dataThreadLocal = ThreadLocal<String>()
suspend fun fromOtherFunction() = "From other function -- ${dataThreadLocal.get()}"

routing {
    get("/hello") {
        // [1]
        launch(this.coroutineContext + dataThreadLocal.asContextElement(value = "world")) {
            val fromHere = async {
                "ThreadLocal value: ${dataThreadLocal.get()}"
            }

            val fromThere = async {
                fromOtherFunction()
            }

            call.respond(fromHere.await() + "," + fromThere.await())
        }

    }
}
```

What I am doing is that making sure all and any functions called from the parent `launch` (labelled [1]) have access to this kind of "scoped" data.

However, my application is quite big and I want this to work for all requests handled by routing and not want to have every route require this wrapping.

What would be really great is:

```
intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features) {
    launch(this.coroutineContext + dataThreadLocal.asContextElement(value = "world")) {
    ...
    }
}

routing {
    get("/hello") {
        val threadLocalValue = dataThreadLocal.get()
    ...
```

Which obviously does not work, becase the coroutine scope in the `intercept` does not enclose the route's coroutine scope.

What I believe happens under the hood is that every call is launched in a parent co-routine scope (similar to how we have 'request threads'). Is there a way for me to modify the context in that? Is there a way where I can tell `ApplicationEngine` to `+` an additional context element whenever this new co-routine context is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a modified `ApplicationEngineEnvironment`. To get access to that, you'll need to write your own EngineMain or similar class. Here's a modified version of the Netty one:

```kotlin
/*
 * Copyright 2014-2019 JetBrains s.r.o and contributors. Use of this source code is governed by the Apache 2.0 license.
 */

import io.ktor.server.config.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi

/**
 * Netty engine
 */
public object EngineMain {
    /**
     * Main function for starting EngineMain with Netty
     * Creates an embedded Netty application with an environment built from command line arguments.
     */
    @JvmStatic
    public fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val applicationEnvironment = commandLineEnvironment(args) { parentCoroutineContext += EmptyCoroutineContext /* your context */ }
        val engine = NettyApplicationEngine(applicationEnvironment) { loadConfiguration(applicationEnvironment.config) }

        engine.start(true)
    }

    internal fun NettyApplicationEngine.Configuration.loadConfiguration(config: ApplicationConfig) {
        val deploymentConfig = config.config("ktor.deployment")
        loadCommonConfiguration(deploymentConfig)
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("requestQueueLimit")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
            requestQueueLimit = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("runningLimit")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
            runningLimit = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("shareWorkGroup")?.getString()?.toBoolean()?.let {
            shareWorkGroup = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("responseWriteTimeoutSeconds")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
            responseWriteTimeoutSeconds = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("requestReadTimeoutSeconds")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
            requestReadTimeoutSeconds = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("tcpKeepAlive")?.getString()?.toBoolean()?.let {
            tcpKeepAlive = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("maxInitialLineLength")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
            maxInitialLineLength = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("maxHeaderSize")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
            maxHeaderSize = it
        }
        deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("maxChunkSize")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
            maxChunkSize = it
        }
    }
}
```

The magic happens on the line:

```kotlin
        val applicationEnvironment = commandLineEnvironment(args) { parentCoroutineContext += EmptyCoroutineContext /* your context */ }
```

You don't have to have a class called `EngineMain`, I just copy-pasted for simplicity (see https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-server/ktor-server-netty/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/netty/EngineMain.kt). You could just take the main function and do configuration manually.